# Generic works until I use it in a Generic SwiftUI View

Tags: generics, swiftui

The following is throwing an error

```
typealias Samples<T:Unit> = [Sample<T>]
typealias Sample = Measurement

protocol Trend<T> {
    associatedtype T:Unit
    func measurement(for date:Date) -> Sample<T>
    init?(samples:Samples<T>)
}


class Analyzer<T:Unit>:Trend {
    private let sample:Sample<T>
    func measurement(for date: Date) -> Sample<T> {
        sample
    }
    required init?(samples: Samples<T>) {
        guard samples.count > 0 else {
            return nil
        }
        self.sample = samples.last!
    }
}

class Snapshot<T:Unit> {
    
    let samples:Samples<T>
    let trend:any Trend<T>
    //if I change this to let trend:Analyzer<T> it works, but I want to use different trends depending on samples
    
    init(samples:Samples<T>) {
        self.samples = samples
        self.trend = Analyzer(samples: samples)!
    }
}

struct MyView<T:Unit>: View {
    
    let snapshot:Snapshot<T>
    var body: some View {
        Text("\(snapshot.trend.measurement(for: .now))")
        //ERROR: Member 'measurement' cannot be used on value of type 'any Trend<T>'; consider using a generic constraint instead
    }
}
```

As I point out, if I make trend concrete in Snapshot, it works, but I want to vary trend depending on the initializer samples.

Where I am going wrong here conceptually?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is the view is complaining as it does not know what the T type of measurement from any Trend is. By changing the function in Trend to return a String instead of the Sample the view is fine. Maybe it is worth having a display function returning the string the views can use and a separate function for Sample if needed.

```
protocol Trend<T> {
    associatedtype T:Unit
    func measurement(for date:Date) -> String
    init?(samples:Samples<T>)
}
```

The longer answer is that when the Snapshot class is initialised the type of the generic T is set and it will be the same for self.samples and self.trend by definition. As you are setting it to a single analyser at the init it makes sense for it to be an Analyzer type. This is known at init and fixed for the life of the class object then. It only makes sense to use any Trend if you are having an array of multiple Trends, or changing the trend in the class later with different types (T). Again by having the string function to describe the Trend in the view this would work fine as the view does not need to cast Ts, it just knows it will get a display string.